# How can i find pairs of number that swap their position in another row in sql?

Tags: sql

I have

```
FirstNumber  SecondNumber
--------------------------
   2        |        3
   4        |        5
   3        |        2
   10       |       11
   5        |        4
```

and the pairs that swap their position are (2,3) and (4,5)
so i have to obtain this query

```
FirstNumber    SecondNumber
------------------------------
   2        |        3  
   4        |        5
```

I don't know where to start

Comment: sorry i will edit the question because the pisition of table wasnt;t this

Comment: It is useful to post an example of your data here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/  that way we can respond with 100% working sql

Answer (score 1):

Use a self `join`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.firstnumber = t2.secondnumber and
        t.secondnumber = t2.firstnumber and
        t.firstnumber < t.secondnumber;
```